# $\pi~$ expanded in terms of the Euler-Mascheroni Constant $\gamma$

Tags: real-analysis, pi, euler-mascheroni-constant

Is there a known expansion of $\pi$ as a function of the Euler-Mascheroni $\gamma$? As in, $$f(\gamma)=\pi h(\pi,\gamma)$$ where $\gamma$ appears alone with only rational arguments like $f(1/2,\gamma)$, and $h(\pi,\gamma)$ is a single, or finite closed form expression of the two constants, like $\pi \zeta(\pi\gamma)$, not considering (trivial) change of variables in integrals as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294712/integral-representation-of-the-euler-mascheroni-constant-involving-pi). [This page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html) seems to have only $$h(\pi,\gamma)\gamma=f(\pi)$$ the inverse of what I ask.

Comment: I don't know which formula at mathworld you are referring to. $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\log x\,dx=-(1/4)\sqrt{\pi}(\gamma+2\log2)$ has both $\pi$ and $\gamma$, but the integral maybe doesn't count as "closed form". Similarly for $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}(\log x)^2\,dx=\gamma^2+(1/6)\pi^2$. $\gamma=\log(4/\pi)-\sum_1^{\infty}(-2)^{-n}(n+1)^{-1}\zeta(n+1)$ has an infinite series. There are also a couple of formulas with infinite products. I don't see any other formula on that page with both $\pi$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: Right, the integral doesn't have $\gamma$ in it, so it doesn't apply. The other expressions expand $\gamma$ in terms of $\pi$, like $\zeta(n+1)$ in the last formula that you wrote. I'm asking about the converse, where $\pi$ is expanded as a function, say, series of $\gamma$.

Comment: So what's to stop you from solving for $\pi$? $\pi=4e^{-\gamma-\sum(-2)^{-n}(n+1)^{-1}\zeta(n+1)}$.

Comment: like $f(\gamma,1)a_{1}+f(\gamma,2)a_{2}....=\pi g(\pi,\gamma)$, where g is some function.

Comment: What you wrote is expanding $\gamma$ in terms of $\pi$. There are many such, but I ask the opposite which I couldn't find.

Comment: What I wrote has $\pi=$ on the left, and an expression in $\gamma$ on the right, which would seem to be exactly what you want. How is $\gamma=\log(4/\pi)-\sum\cdots$ expanding $\gamma$ in terms of $\pi$, but $\pi=4e^{-\gamma-\sum\cdots}$ not expanding $\pi$ in terms of $\gamma$?

Comment: Haha, alright then.